# Half of the triangles on a mesh are unusually lit

Tags: opengl, mesh, surface

I have a mesh that i generate from exported mesh data. The mesh has some big triangles which i split in to smaller triangles. After splitting, about half of the normals seem off.

For each new vertice i create, i also create a new normal with data i copy from one of the other normals on the triangle im splitting. After splitting, my normals array has the same amount as the vertices array. Yet, the following problem occurs:

[image: Exhibit A] (animated version here https://i.gyazo.com/2ae87dda9bfbff16b0be421941e8bca6.gif ]

Im using A VBO mesh style. Any help is much appreciated!

#### Edit by datenwolf to incorporate information from comment:

With face culling enabled the rendering outcome looks like this:

[image: Exhibit B]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rendering suffers from two problems:

- Z fighting: (apparently your mesh is "double walled") where the rendering of the two walls "conflict" in the depth test. This can be mitigated by enabling back face culling (`glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`)

However for backface culling to work, you have to address the other problem which is

- inconsistent face windings / normal directions: It seems that half of the faces in your mesh are specified clockwise, with the other half counterclockwise. Automated winding regularization is a subject too complicated to touch in this Q&A format. The immediate recommendation would be to load the mesh into a 3D modeller that offers this function and fix it there (e.g. Blender, which has the function "Make Normals Consistent", Ctrl+N hotkey in Edit-Mode).

Comment: Thank you. The Z-Fighting indeed seems to be a problem. With backface culling enabled the result now looks like this: https://gyazo.com/878d14a334f1f71e182e8a2eaaff4f59 . Unfortunately i have to solve the triangle splitting programatically, because it is part of a larger process in this piece of software.

I do sort the triangles on their indices like 2, 14, 16 and never 14, 2 , 16. But i suppose this does not solve the (counter) clockwise problem?

Comment: @Satchmode: Now with the second image it's absolutely clear, that you've got a winding problem there. A simple, mechanical reordering on the generated will not do the trick. You have to look at the actual geometry. What you have to do is, for each edge at which triangles neighbour, calculate the normal of each triangle using the order of indices as in your data and if the normals point into opposite directions select one of the triangles, which needs its winding order to be flipped (simply by exchanging two of its indices in the face index list).

Comment: @Satchmode: The devil is in the details: What about triangles forming a wedge? In that case the correct winding is for both of them having their normals point into roughly the opposite direction. So you also have to somehow define an "inside" and an "outside" and bring that into account.

Comment: @Satchmode: However looking at your images, there's a very strong regularity in the way, the winding is mixed up. If the mesh is generated algorithmically, then it might be as easy as swapping two of the indices of every second generated triangle, or similar. Actually this looks like the output of a remesher, or some implicit surface tesselator, so instead of trying to fix the mesh as an afterthought I'd try to fix the generating process.

Comment: Thank you, the information and the depth of elaboration will be enough of a direction for me to solve the problem. This is a new account but once i get my 15 pts, the karma is yours. Thanks again!